# Can't write to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't write to Firebase. I use exactly as in the tutorial but it's not working.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.setValue("aaa");
...
```

Also I have changed the rules to:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
   }
}
```

Also my google-services.json is just downloaded from the project.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, as of March 2021, it seems the problem was the `classpath` of `Gradle` dependency that caused the issue.

In Project-Level `build.gradle`:
I have changed:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
```

to:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the reference branch in the database.getReference() like:

```
database.getReference("reference name")
```

You can't set the main branch value, you can only add references to it.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)?  It is true that you cannot upload a file to the storage root.  I don't know of any similar restriction on the database root.  I am able to successfully write data using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().setValue()`.

Comment: I remember I added reference name also but still didn't worked. I restarted my whole PC and now it's working.